# Installing Phusion Passenger onto an existing VPS with PHP application

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger, vps

Will installing phusion passenger (apache) onto an existing server break an existing site implementation that uses PHP?

I am working in rails, and I'd like to run both PHP and Rails applications from the same rackspace VPS. However, i am afraid to install passenger out of fear that it will take down our live site.

I built a vhost for the rails, and have it all setup, but this is holding me back.

Any advice is appreciated.

thanks!

Joel

Comment: it "should" be possible for them to coexist...

Answer (score 0):

try making full backups before attempting if possible failure is holding you back. i had a similar experience with installing apache+php before i install passenger with ruby for redmine installation, worked without any errors.
consider reading a little before proceeding to installation http://www.modrails.com/install.html.

Comment: i read the brightbox article before posting this. I was hoping to hear from some others who have done the same without issue.

So you installed passenger on top of apache and it didnt effect your PHP app?

Comment: its rare for an apache module such as passenger to affect mod_php, because its an entire different module, i have an ubuntu server with apache2+passenger+php running apps such as wordpress(php) / redmine(ruby), just don't hesitate if you have made a backup, you have the option to restore VPS after a failed attempt.

Comment: i have backups, i think i'm going to spin up another VPS, and use a backup image on that, and use that as a test. I'm hesitant to take a chance on knocking down the live site (not an option)